# How to effectively validate that all parts of string are numbers?

Tags: php

I would like to validate that given string consists of numbers split by slash only:

```
validate('7515/1453') // true
validate('7515/1453/4') // true
validate('7515') // false
validate('') // false
validate('abc/4') // false
```

My solution:

```
function validate($str) {
  $valid = false;
  if (($parts = explode($str, '/')) !== false) {
    $valid = true;
    foreach($parts as $part) {
      if (!ctype_digit($part)) {
        $valid = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $valid;
}
```

The solution works, but feels a little bit clumsy. Is there a way to make it better?

Comment: So you want to make sure your string contains at least 1 slash and at least 1 number? e.g. `/1`, `1/` or `12/23` ?

Comment: This is more of a code review question. You might be able to get it on-topic for SO if you highlight a specific part of your solution that you want different / are unhappy about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a regular expression which says "start of string, one or more digits, followed by a slash. (optionally repeated). Then more digits, then the end".

```
^(\d+\/)+\d+$
```

e.g.

```
$re = "/^(\\d+\\/)+\\d+$/"; 
$str = "7515/1453"; 

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/tR4tL9/1 - click on "Unit Tests" in the menu on the left, your tests are in there; click the 'play' arrow to run them.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't consider the option to use regular expressions for this. I also need to check the lenght of the number parts so this is in my opinion the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `filter_var_array` and validate your parts.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php

Regex free Example:

```
function validate($string) {
    $parts = explode('/', $string);

    if (count($parts) <= 1) {
        return false;
    }

    $validatedParts = filter_var_array($parts, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    return !(bool)array_search(false, $validatedParts, true);
}
```

Comment: This code fails when only one number is given. See code

Comment: Arrgghh my bad :) sry fixed...thanks!

Comment: No worries, looks good. +1